# 22.04 Mouse grabbing Firefox tabs

Tags: 22.04

Just installed. besides Firefox freezing and force quitting every time I open a few tabs..
I cant use Firefox without the mouse grabbing tabs instead of clicking on them.

Comment: If you're using a wireless mouse, I'd suggest checking your batteries (ie. trying it with fresh batteries), as I've often found weird behavior with wireless mouse when batteries are weak & thus signal being received is incomplete/corrupted etc.

Comment: I probably should've mentioned I came from windows and everything functioned fine.